# How can I color nodes of a graphNEL graph?

Tags: r, graphviz, graph-visualization

I'm using `graphNEL` objects from `gRbase` and `Rgraphviz` for plotting and would like to color the nodes of the graph in different (specified) colors when plotting.  For example, how could I plot this graph with `a` and `b` in blue and `c` and `d` in red?

```
library(Rgraphviz)
library(gRbase)
mygraph = dag(~a:c + b:c + b:d)
plot(mygraph)
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work ;

```
nAttrs<-list()
nAttrs$color <- c(a = "blue", b = "blue", c = "red", d = "red")
plot(g1, nodeAttrs = nAttrs)
```

see also `getDefaultAttrs()` to get all the graph attributes with default values.